# Show information from a model and save it in and other model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a queryset that gets information from a model and shows it in a template.

```
datos = RecetaDatosMedicoPaciente.objects.get(pk=id)
```

what I need is that information, save it in an other model, but I don't know who to do it, 'cause the name of the variables are different.

This are my 2 models I get the info from RecetaDatosMedicoPaciente and I need to save it in proveedores_farmacia.

model.py

```
 class RecetaDatosMedicoPaciente(models.Model):
    fecha_receta_2 = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    hora_receta = models.TimeField(auto_now=True)
    nombre_medico_3 = models.ForeignKey(Medico, related_name='med', null=True)
    fecha_nacimiento_4 = models.DateField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    datosmedicospaciente_credencial = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    nombre_miembro_6 = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    apellido_miembro_6 = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    edad_Miembro_7 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    sexo_miembro_8 = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    empresa_empleadora_9 = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    plan_inscrito_10 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    vigencia_receta_11 = models.DateField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    codigo_diagnostico_12 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    codigo_diagnostico_13 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    codigo_diagnostico_14 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    codigo_diagnostico_15 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    codigo_diagnostico_16 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    codigo_diagnostico_17 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)




class proveedores_farmacia(models.Model):
    farmacia_folio = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_tipocambio = models.IntegerField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_nombremiembro = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_credencial = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_apellidomiembro = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_fechasurtido = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_horasurtido = models.TimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_fechareceto = models.DateField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_horareceto = models.TimeField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_copago = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_total = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_total_copago = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True);
    farmacia_diferencia_pago = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True);
```

Comment: please post your code, as your question stands now it does not provide enough information to be answerable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in views or where ever, but you can also set up a new file to do this.

make a new file in the same directory as your model.

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_site.settings")
from your_app_name.models import RecetaDatosMedicoPaciente, proveedores_farmacia


datos = RecetaDatosMedicoPaciente.objects.get(pk=id)

proveedores_create = proveedores_farmacia.objects.create(
farmacia_folio = datos.fecha_receta_2
farmacia_tipocambio = datos.hora_receta
farmacia_nombremiembro = datos.nombre_medico_3
farmacia_credencial = datos.etc
farmacia_apellidomiembro = datos.etc
farmacia_fechasurtido = datos.etc
farmacia_horasurtido = datos.etc
farmacia_fechareceto = datos.etc
farmacia_horareceto = datos.etc
farmacia_copago = datos.etc
farmacia_total = datos.etc
farmacia_total_copago = datos.etc
farmacia_diferencia_pago = datos.etc
)
```